# Defining a schema that allows attributes from mixed namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I am struggling with trying to develop a schema which allows attributes from mixed namespaces.

Here is xxx_schema2.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="qualified"  
  targetNamespace="http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2"
  xmlns:xxx="http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2"> 

  <xs:attributeGroup name="schema2AttributeGroup">
    <xs:attribute name="schema2Attribute1 " type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="schema2Attribute2 " type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

</xs:schema>
```

Here is xxx_schema1.xsd which imports xxx_schema2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xxx="http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2">

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2" schemaLocation="xxx_schema2.xsd"/>

  <!-- ROOT ELEMENT -->
  <xs:element name="rootElement" type="rootElementType" />

  <!-- COMPLEX TYPES -->
  <xs:complexType name="rootElementType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="xxx:schema2AttributeGroup"/>  
            <xs:attribute name="schema1Attribute1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
     </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the XML document which I would like to validate against xxx_schema1.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <rootElement xmlns:xxx='http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2/' 
schema1Attribute1="foo"
xxx:schema2Attribute1="bar"
xxx:schema2Attribute2="far" />
```

When the Saxon-EE parser attempts to validate the XML document against the schema, the errors it generates are literally:

```
Engine name: Saxon-EE 9.3.0.5
Severity: error
Description: Attribute @xxx:schema2Attribute1 is not allowed on element <rootElement>
(it would be allowed in namespace http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2)
```

AND

```
Engine name: Saxon-EE 9.3.0.5
Severity: error
Description: Attribute @xxx:schema2Attribute2 is not allowed on element <rootElement>
(it would be allowed in namespace http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2)
```

Please can you help me understand what I have done wrong in my schema definitions or XML document which prevent the validation from being successful? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  It's not clear what you're asking.  Have you tried it?  if it didn't work, what happened?

Comment: I am being told that "Attribute @xxx:schema2Attribute1 is not allowed on element <rootElement> (It would be allowed in namespace <namespace for schema 2>)"

In terms of what I'm asking.. I would like to know how one would generally structured schema2, schema1 and the XML document in order to get this to validate correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you showed us the actual schema fragments you're talking about, plus the error in full, rather than describing them in english.

Comment: I have updated the original question with the two schema documents and the one XML document. The errors provided by the parser are also included. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace declaration for `http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2` in your instance XML has a trailing slash and does not match your Schema's declared namespace.

Remove the trailing slash and it validates just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <rootElement xmlns:xxx='http://www.mrbouffant.com/schema2' 
schema1Attribute1="foo"
xxx:schema2Attribute1="bar"
xxx:schema2Attribute2="far" />
```